# MVC SitemapProiver, adding a new link to sitemap when action occurs

Tags: c#, mvcsitemapprovider

I´m in need of inserting multiple external links to my MVCSitemap. Basically, there is a parent node called 'LINKS', which I will populate with URLs from another app, thru an admin View.I was wondering if there's a built-in method that given a parameter could find a Parent node and insert to it a child node as if I was editing the document manually.

Answer (score 0):

The recommended way of achieving this is to use a custom [IDynamicNodeProvider](https://github.com/maartenba/MvcSiteMapProvider/wiki/Defining-sitemap-nodes-using-IDynamicNodeProvider) or ISiteMapNodeProvider to supply the nodes, and use [SiteMapCacheReleaseAttribute](https://github.com/maartenba/MvcSiteMapProvider/wiki/Defining-sitemap-nodes-using-IDynamicNodeProvider#caching) on action methods that modify SiteMap data to invalidate the cache so the SiteMap will load the new nodes the next time it is accessed.

```
[HttpPost]
[SiteMapCacheRelease]
public ActionResult Edit(int id, Product product)
{
    try
    {
        using (var db = new CRUDExample())
        {
            var model = (from p in db.Product
                     where p.Id == id
                     select p).FirstOrDefault();
            if (model != null)
            {
                model.Name = product.Name;
                db.SaveChanges();
            }
        }
        return RedirectToAction("Index");
    }
    catch
    {
        return View();
    }
}
```

SiteMapCacheReleaseAttribute should be placed on all add, edit, and delete action methods that you would like to see the changes happen immediately, and should generally only apply to the [HttpPost] side since the [HttpGet] generally doesn't change any data.